# ERROR AL ACTULIZAR DATOS DROPDOWN LIST

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlist

tengo el siguiente problema, resulta ser que tengo un proyecto en asp.net c# en el cual estoy haciendo una tabla de usuarios con privilegios para entrar en una pagina, para insertar los datos gridview pido los datos de 3 textBox y 2 dropdown list los cuales al inserto por medio de un boton y no me da problema , mi problema está en como actualizar los datos que selecciono de mi gridview y actualizarlos por medio de un boton ya que no se como utilizar los Dropdownlist soy nuevo en esto espero y me puedan apoyar, en seguida anexo el codigo que hice en el boton de agregar

```
    protected void BtnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Miconexion"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("insert into usuario(userName,password,nombre,rolid,estatus) values('" +
          this.txtUsuario.Text + "','" +
          txtContra.Text+ "','" +
          txtbNombre_usu.Text + "','" +
          ddlRol.SelectedItem.Value+ "','" +
          ddEstatus.SelectedItem.Value + "')", conexion);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //MOSTRAR MENSAJES DE ALERTA DE INSERCIÓN 
        try
        {
             ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('SE INSERTÓ EL USUARIO CON ÉXITO.')", true);
        }
        catch
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('NO SE PUDO INSERTAR EL USUARIO')", true);
        }


        BindData();
        conexion.Close();

    }
```